# Printing items in a List ( in lots of two )

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have hit a road block and am rusty after walking away from code.
But I'm trying to print my list of items in pairings of 2.

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string>()
 { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Grapes", "Apricot" };
```

I want to print the pairings like:

> Group 1: Apple, Banana
>
> Group 2: Orange, Pear
>
> Group 3: Grapes, Apricot

At present I have a `foreach`

```
foreach(var item in fruits)
{
    Count++;
    Console.Write("Group" + count + ": " + item .....); // <--stuck
    fruits.Remove(per);
    Console.Write("," + per);
}
```

Reason I'm deleting the item from the list is so I don't get a double up of `fruits`.
Or, if you have a better idea it would be greatly appreciated. Please correct me if I'm making a mistake in your opinion.

Comment: What happens with an odd number of elements? You could always use a `for` loop and index in manually.

Comment: You can´t iterate a list and remove items from it at the same time. Create a temporary copy of your list and iterate this one. Then you can remove the elements from your original list.

Comment: good point if it was odd then maybe its own group. as in for(int I = 0; 1 < fruits.count; I++); cw(fruits[I] + fruits[I+1] etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` with the integer division trick:

```
List<List<string>> lotsOftwo = fruits.Select((fruit, index) => new {fruit, index})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2, x => x.fruit).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

That works because integer division truncates the decimal part.

Without LINQ you could use this slightly more effficient approach:

```
var lotsOftwo = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.Count; i += 2)
{
    lotsOftwo.Add(fruits.GetRange(i, Math.Min(2, fruits.Count - i)));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was so in deep into my answer that I didn´t notice your edit. Deleted my answer.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: np, your answer had still an issue if the list contains an odd number of fruits. You got no exception but the last item would have been omitted. My approach will insert the last remaining item. **Edit** well, maybe that is desired, it wasn't clear

Comment: That´s why I simply deleted it as it doesn´t add any value to the question.

Comment: +1 to this. Linq, aggregate, fancy techniques... With a List a simple for and += 2 is the simplest and fastest thing that can work, so it gets my vote.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your help..i did have an issue but your basic structure helped solve this , I used your more efficient for loop. I made 2 temp strings to hold each iterations value ( [i] & [I+1] ) and printed out

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ and `GroupBy` method. Like this:

```
var result = fruits
             .Select((c, i) => new { Index = i, Content = c })
             .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)
             .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Content).ToList())
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements from a List while you are iterating through it in a foreach is a terrible idea.  I'm not even sure it's syntactically legal.

Also, you should be iterating through the List, casting as string, not var:

```
    bool endSet = false;
    int groupCount = 1;
    string group = "";
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string fruit in fruits)
    {
        if (endSet)
        {
            group += fruit;
            outputBuilder.Append(group);
            group = "";
        }
        else
        {
            group += "Group " + (groupCount++).ToString() + fruit + ", ";
        }

        endSet = !endSet;
    }

    if ((fruits.Count) % 2 == 1)
    {
       outputBuilder.Append(group);
    }

    Console.Writeline(outputBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to this problem would also be:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CreateChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int chunkLength)
{
    if (chunkLength < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkLength));

    using (var e = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return createChunk(e, chunkLength);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> createChunk<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int chunkLength)
{
    var counter = 0;

    do
    {
        yield return enumerator.Current;

        if (++counter == chunkLength)
            yield break;

    } while (enumerator.MoveNext());
}
```

And now,

```
var seq = new[] {  "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Grapes", "Apricot" };
var chunks = seq.CreateChunks(2);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
       chunks.Select((c, i) => $"Group {i + 1}: {string.Join(", ", c)}")));
```

Would print out the expected output:

```
Group 1: Apple, Banana
Group 2: Orange, Pear
Group 3: Grapes, Apricot
```